# How to load a text file, add it to an array and change it into an object?

Tags: java, arrays, netbeans, text-files, dao

I am creating a program to display restaurant reviews which are saved in a text file. The text file is read in via the DAOimpl class as shown.

```
public class DAOlmpl implements DAOInterface {
    static final char DELIMITER=',';   

    /**@Override*/
    public Repository load(String filename) {

        Repository repository = new Repository();

        try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filename))) { 
            String[] temp;
            String line = br.readLine();
            while(line!=null){
                temp=line.split(Character.toString(DELIMITER));        
                String name = stripQuotes(temp[0]);
                String location = stripQuotes(temp[1]);
                Restaurant restaurant = new Restaurant(name, location) {};
                int lines = Integer.parseInt(temp[2]);
                ArrayList<Review> review = new ArrayList<>();

                for (int i=0; i<lines; i++) {
                    restaurant.addReviews(review);
                }
                repository.add(restaurant);                
                line = br.readLine();                
            }
            br.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(DAOlmpl.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        return repository;
    }
}
```

and then is transfered over to the Restaurant class using this method.

```
public void addReviews(Review review) {
    this.reviewsCollection.add(review);
}
```

However, I cant seem to get it over into the Restruant class as its in the form of an arraylist and not an object. I've treid many wayas to correct it, but cant get it working

Comment: The last part of your question is not clear . Please make the question clearer. What is that you want to achieve?

Comment: I'm not sure I understood how reviews parsing should work, it seems sth is missing: at least the construction of at least one Review object. You just make the ArrayList that suppose to store reviews, but you don't put there anything. How does Review class look like???

But the solution to the current issue can be derived directly from the last sentence of your question: you either need to change the signature (and probably the implementation) of `addReviews` to accept `ArrayList` OR you need to change what `review` variable is and instantiate it e. g. as `Review review = new Review(...)`

Answer (score 0):

If I read it correct, may this could be the Solution:

```
List<Review> reviews = new ArrayList<>();

for (Review review : reviews) {
   restaurant.addReview(review);
}
```

and for the function

```
public void addReview(Review review) {
   this.reviewsCollection.add(review);
}
```

So you add each Review separately what is in your list.

But you don't put any Review object in to your List so your list will be empty in this example.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Some logic is missing from your code. I noticed that you did not create any Review object. To remedy this, you could create Review objects, one after another and call the `Restaurant.addReviews(Review);` method for each Review object created. This could be done in the for loop as shown below:

```
        for (int i=0; i<lines; i++) {

            // Create a review object
            //
            Review review = createReview();

            // Add the review object
            //
            restaurant.addReviews(review);
        }
```

The above would obviate the need for the ArrayList of reviews.

In addition, The method to add reviews shown below...

```
public void addReviews(Review review) {
    this.reviewsCollection.add(review);
}
```

...could be broken down into 2 methods. One method named: `addReview` to add a single Review and the other named: `addReviews` to add many Reviews. Notice the letter 's' missing from the former and added to the later method name. Use the 's' to signify adding multiple... See both methods below:

```
public void addReviews(List<Review> reviews) {
    this.reviewsCollection.addAll(reviews);
}

public void addReview(Review review) {
    this.reviewsCollection.add(review);
}
```

There are more observations. But I simply answered the immediate pressing (i.e your question).

Now, lets put it all together:

```
public class DAOlmpl implements DAOInterface {

    static final char DELIMITER=',';   

    /**@Override*/
    @Override
    public Repository load(String filename) {

        Repository repository = new Repository();

        try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filename))) { 

            String line = br.readLine();

            while(line!=null){

                Restaurant restaurant = createRestaurantHavingReviews(line)

                repository.add(restaurant);                

                line = br.readLine();                
            }

            br.close();

        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(DAOlmpl.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

        return repository;
    }

    public Restaurant createRestaurantHavingReviews(String line) {

        String [] temp=line.split(Character.toString(DELIMITER));        

        Restaurant restaurant = createRestaurant(temp);

        int lines = Integer.parseInt(temp[2]);

        for (int i=0; i<lines; i++) {

            Review review = createReview(temp);

            restaurant.addReview(review);
        }

        return restaurant;            
    }

    public Restaurant createRestaurant(String[]temp) {
        String name = stripQuotes(temp[0]);
        String location = stripQuotes(temp[1]);
        Restaurant restaurant = new Restaurant(name, location) {};
        return restaurant;
    }

    public Review createReview(String[]temp) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Please implement me!");
    }
}
```

The above code is more readable and if you **implement the** `public Review createReview(String[]temp)` **method above**.. we could take it up from there if you have more questions.

Hope this helps.